# Is data constructor a function?

Tags: haskell

I found the following example [here](http://monads.haskell.cz/html/class.html)

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    Nothing  >>= f = Nothing
    (Just x) >>= f = f x
    return         = Just
```

The `return` method is defined in the pointfree style, which I know is applicable to functions, but here we have a data constructor whose declaration syntax looks different from the one of functions let alone its purpose.

Another tutorial [says](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor):

> Data constructors are first class values in Haskell and actually have a type. For instance, the type of the
>   Left
>   constructor of the
>   Either
>   data type is:
>
> Left :: forall b a. a -> Either a b
>
> As first class values, they may be passed to functions, held in a list, be data elements of other algebraic data types and so forth.

So can anyone make it clear what data constructors are and how they are different from functions if anything.

Answer (score 6):

One specific difference, at least, is that data (value) constructors can be used in pattern matches while functions that are not data constructors cannot. It is the only real difference I can think of, other than the fact that "nullary" data constructors (think `Nothing`) are, well, *nullary*.

Comment: The way I view it is that the constructor is a function and the deconstructor is a pattern matching thing you get for free that looks like the constructor but they are two different things. Maybe that just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Data constructor is just a function with eta-reduction:

```
Just === \x -> Just x

Left === \x -> Left x
```

But `Nothing` is a function without arguments

Comment: I believe talking about "function[s] without arguments" muddles things unnecessarily. See [this forceful take on the issue by Conal Elliot](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell).